# Resolving airwires in EAGLE for valid wires

Tags: eaglecad, layout

I have a board(brd) file in Eagle which shows several airwires for connected nets. I have tried to fix the airwire via ratsnesting, confirming net names and just about every resolution I could conceive or fiddle with. What is the issue here?

**Question**: How do you resolve the airwire in the illustration below?

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like the connection points of the track and the rectangular pad are misaligned - perhaps there is a short 45 degree segment of track placing its "hot spot" offset from the pad's hot spot.  In Protel, I'd set the tracks and pads to show as outlines to more easily see, and correct, the fault.  Don't kow if Eagle can do that...

Comment: WOW, that solved it!!!! I will post this as an answer but would prefer if you posted it as the answer and then I'll mark it as solution!!

Comment: @PeterBennett in Eagle if you want to see the outlines, you just change the fill mode in the layers panel.

Comment: Hi Tom, please give a wee bit more supplemental clarity, context and detail. I have no idea what you are describing or referring to so... :(

Comment: @J-Dizzle the comment was for Peter - he was talking about showing outlines to make things more clear, but wasn't sure if you could do it in Eagle.

Comment: hehe, sweet. cause i was sooo confused... ;)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the connection points of the track and the rectangular pad are misaligned - perhaps there is a short 45 degree segment of track placing its "hot spot" offset from the pad's hot spot. In Protel, I'd set the tracks and pads to show as outlines to more easily see, and correct, the fault. The outline tracks mode can show up other confusing things, like multiple vertices along a straight track, which can make dragging a track section difficult.

@Tom Carpenter reports that in Eagle if you want to see the outlines, you just change the fill mode in the layers panel.

A similar fault that I've experienced in KiCad occurs when you place a track along a row of pads - KiCad (and perhaps other programs) won't recognize a track simply passing over a pad as connected unless you actually click on the pad as you pass it.

Comment: For reference, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XOFhk.png) is how to change the fill style to make seeing trace outlines easier.